# How do I get Swagger to follow extends?

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2, swagger

I'm using Swagger PHP for ZF2 to generate API docs.

However, Some of my Controllers extends another Controller, and I can't get Swagger to include annotations from the parent class.

Consider this:

```
/**
 * ProjectController Class
 * @SWG\Resource(
 *     basePath="projects",
 *     description="Actions for Projects"
 * )
 * @see AbstractItemController
 */
class ProjectController extends AbstractItemController
{
 ...
}
```

Any Swagger annotations in the ProjectController works just fine, however I can't get any annotations in AbstractItemController to be included in the documentation for ProjectController.

Any ideas?

Thanks!